# How is this tcp socket code handling the rx buffer?

Tags: c, tcp

I came across this tcp server example, provided with the Altera Nios II processor, and I'm not getting the section on handling the rx_buffer.

**`server.h`**

```
typedef struct SSS_SOCKET {
    enum {
        READY, COMPLETE, CLOSE
    } state;
    int fd;
    int close;
    INT8U rx_buffer[SSS_RX_BUF_SIZE];
    INT8U *rx_rd_pos; /* position we've read up to */
    INT8U *rx_wr_pos; /* position we've written up to */
} SSSConn;
```

**`server.c`**

```
int data_used = 0, rx_code = 0;
INT8U *lf_addr;

conn->rx_rd_pos = conn->rx_buffer;
conn->rx_wr_pos = conn->rx_buffer;

printf("[sss_handle_receive] processing RX data\n");

while (conn->state != CLOSE) {
    /* Find the Carriage return which marks the end of the header */
    lf_addr = strchr(conn->rx_buffer, '\n');

    if (lf_addr) {
        /* go off and do whatever the user wanted us to do */
        sss_exec_command(conn);
    }
    /* No newline received? Then ask the socket for data */
    else {
        rx_code = recv(conn->fd, conn->rx_wr_pos,
                SSS_RX_BUF_SIZE - (conn->rx_wr_pos - conn->rx_buffer) -1, 0);

        if (rx_code > 0) {
            conn->rx_wr_pos += rx_code;

            /* Zero terminate so we can use string functions */
            *(conn->rx_wr_pos + 1) = 0;
        }
    }

    /* 
     * When the quit command is received, update our connection state so that
     * we can exit the while() loop and close the connection
     */
    conn->state = conn->close ? CLOSE : READY;

    /* Manage buffer */
    data_used = conn->rx_rd_pos - conn->rx_buffer;
    memmove(conn->rx_buffer, conn->rx_rd_pos,
            conn->rx_wr_pos - conn->rx_rd_pos);
    conn->rx_rd_pos = conn->rx_buffer;
    conn->rx_wr_pos -= data_used;
    memset(conn->rx_wr_pos, 0, data_used);
}
```

Specifically, I don't see the purpose of the data_used variable. `rx_rd_pos` is pointing to `rx_buffer` and there doesn't appear to be an operation on either, so how will they be different? In fact, the only thing that seems to happen under `Manage buffer` is the copying of data into `rx_buffer`. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I can't seem to see it.

Thanks for any help in advance.

**Edit:** Here's the **sss_exec_command()** function.

```
void sss_exec_command(SSSConn* conn) {
int bytes_to_process = conn->rx_wr_pos - conn->rx_rd_pos;
INT8U tx_buf[SSS_TX_BUF_SIZE];
INT8U *tx_wr_pos = tx_buf;

INT8U error_code;

/*
 * "SSSCommand" is declared static so that the data will reside 
 * in the BSS segment. This is done because a pointer to the data in 
 * SSSCommand
 * will be passed via SSSLedCommandQ to the LEDManagementTask.  
 * Therefore SSSCommand cannot be placed on the stack of the 
 * SSSSimpleSocketServerTask, since the LEDManagementTask does not 
 * have access to the stack of the SSSSimpleSocketServerTask.
 */
static INT32U SSSCommand;

SSSCommand = CMD_LEDS_BIT_0_TOGGLE;

while (bytes_to_process--) {
    SSSCommand = toupper(*(conn->rx_rd_pos++));

    if (SSSCommand >= ' ' && SSSCommand <= '~') {
        tx_wr_pos += sprintf(tx_wr_pos,
                "--> Simple Socket Server Command %c.\n",
                (char) SSSCommand);
        if (SSSCommand == CMD_QUIT) {
            tx_wr_pos += sprintf(tx_wr_pos,
                    "Terminating connection.\n\n\r");
            conn->close = 1;
        } else {
            error_code = OSQPost(SSSLEDCommandQ, (void *) SSSCommand);

            alt_SSSErrorHandler(error_code, 0);
        }
    }
}

send(conn->fd, tx_buf, tx_wr_pos - tx_buf, 0);

return;
```

}

Answers below are correct. I missed the pointer arithmetic on rx_rd in the command function :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That section removes data from the buffer once it has been processed. The code you posted never uses the data stores in the buffer, but the `sss_exec_command` function will, after a newline is received. That function is passed the connection, so it can increment the read position by however much it uses.

After data is used, the buffer management section reclaims the space. The amount of data left in the buffer is the difference between the write and read positions. This much data is moved from the write position to the start of the buffer, then the read and write pointer are updated to their new positions. The read position is set to the start of the buffer, and the write position is decremented by `data_used`, which is the original difference between the start of the buffer and the read pointer, i.e. the amount of data used.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code actually works, then `data_used = conn->rx_rd_pos - conn->rx_buffer` implies `rx_rd_pos` is being changed; this would be being changed when the code has consumed the data written into the buffer (it's written in at `rx_wr_pos` and consumed from `rx_rd_pos`). This would imply that `sss_exec_command(conn)` is adjusting `conn`. Is that the case?